# Regular expression with if condition activity in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to check if a file name contains a date pattern (`dd-mmm-yyy`) in it using `if condition` activity in Azure Data Factory. For example: The file name I have is like somestring_23-Apr-1984.csv which has a date pattern in it.

I get the file name using `Get Metadata` activity and passing it to the `if condition` activity where I want to check if the file name has the date pattern in it and based on the result I would like to perform different tasks. The only way I know to do this is by using regex to check if the pattern is available in the file name string but, Azure does not have a regex solution mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).

Is there any other way to achieve my requirement in ADF? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,there is no regex in expression.There is another way to do this,but it is very complex.

First,get the date string(23-Apr-1984) from the output of `Get Metadata`.

Then,split the date string and determine whether each part match date pattern.

Below is my test pipeline:

[image: total]

First `Set variable`:

```
name: fileName
value: @split(split(activity('MyGetMetadataActivity').output.itemName,'_')[1],'.csv')[0]
```

Second `Set variable`:

```
name: fileArray
value: @split(variables('fileName'),'-')
```

`If Condition`:

```
Expression:@and(contains(variables('DateArray'),variables('fileArray')[0]),contains(variables('MonthArray'),variables('fileArray')[1]))
```

By the way,I want to compare date with 0 and 30 originally,but `greaterOrEquals()` doesn't support nested properties.So I use `contains()`.

Hope this can help you.